# How should I make a prepared statement here?

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I am trying to execute that query using mysql2:

```
const [[questions]] = 
  await db.promise().execute(
    'SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`topic` LIKE ?', 
    ['%' + text + '%']
  );
```

but get nothing from database.

Then I tried this:

```
const [[questions]] = 
  await db.promise().execute(
    "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`topic` LIKE '?'",
    ['%' + text + '%']
  );
```

and still nothing.

How should I make prepared statement here?

Comment: I found this link useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677274/transaction-for-prepared-statements-using-node-mssql

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
let query = `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions.topic LIKE '%${text}%'`;

const data = await db.promise().execute(query);
console.log('data ==>',data);
```

Comment: Does the library automatically prevent SQL injection when used this way?