# Node MySQL second query gets executed faster than first query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a problem. In my NodeJS API. I use the `Node-Binance-API` package to use the API from Binance. In this API I can subscribe to account changes using a websocket. The function to subscribe to my account looks like the following:

```
exports.subscribeAccount = async (agentId) => {
    binance.websockets.userData((response) => {
        if (eventType === "outboundAccountPosition") {
            console.log("outboundAccountPosition")
        }
        else if (eventType === "executionReport") {
            const order = Order.executionReportToOrder(response, agentId);
            order.save();
        }
    })
}
```

The `order.save()` method looks like this:

```
save() {
    let sql = `
    INSERT INTO \`Order\` (
                orderId, agentId, symbol, clientOrderId, side, orderType, timeInForce, orderQuantity, orderPrice, stopPrice, icebergQuantity, originalClientOrderId, currentExecutionType, currentOrderStatus, orderRejectReason, lastExecutedQuantity, cumulativeFilledQuantity, lastExecutedPrice, commissionAmount, commissionAsset, transactionTime, tradeId, isOrderOnBook, isTradeMakerSide, creationTime, cumulativeQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity, lastQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity, quoteOrderQuantity
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currentExecutionType=VALUES(currentExecutionType), currentOrderStatus=VALUES(currentOrderStatus), orderRejectReason=VALUES(orderRejectReason), lastExecutedQuantity=VALUES(lastExecutedQuantity), cumulativeFilledQuantity=VALUES(cumulativeFilledQuantity), lastExecutedPrice=VALUES(lastExecutedPrice), commissionAmount=VALUES(commissionAmount), commissionAsset=VALUES(commissionAsset), transactionTime=VALUES(transactionTime), tradeId=VALUES(tradeId), isOrderOnBook=VALUES(isOrderOnBook), isTradeMakerSide=VALUES(isTradeMakerSide), creationTime=VALUES(creationTime), cumulativeQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity=VALUES(cumulativeQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity), lastQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity=VALUES(lastQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity), quoteOrderQuantity=VALUES(quoteOrderQuantity);`;

    return db.execute(sql, [
        this.orderId,
        this.agentId,
        this.symbol,
        this.clientOrderId,
        this.side,
        this.orderType,
        this.timeInForce,
        this.orderQuantity,
        this.orderPrice,
        this.stopPrice,
        this.icebergQuantity,
        this.originalClientOrderId,
        this.currentExecutionType,
        this.currentOrderStatus,
        this.orderRejectReason,
        this.lastExecutedQuantity,
        this.cumulativeFilledQuantity,
        this.lastExecutedPrice,
        this.commissionAmount,
        this.commissionAsset,
        this.transactionTime,
        this.tradeId,
        this.isOrderOnBook,
        this.isTradeMakerSide,
        this.creationTime,
        this. cumulativeQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity,
        this.lastQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity,
        this.quoteOrderQuantity
    ]);
}
```

But now I have the following problem. The websocket works great and it pushes updates about orders. When I enter an order that gets executed instantly, this method gets called twice, right after each other. The first call is the `NEW` order and the second one is the `FILLED` order. the `order.save()` function writes the object to the database using the `db.execute()` function of the `mysql2` package, but I can see that sometimes the second query gets executed faster than the first, so the final state of the order in my database is `NEW`. How can I prevent this from happening? Can I cancel the first query when I see the second one coming in or let them execute after each other?

### TABLE

The SHOW CREATE TABLE `Order` results in:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
  `orderId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `agentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `clientOrderId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `side` enum('BUY','SELL') NOT NULL,
  `orderType` enum('MARKET','LIMIT','STOP_LOSS','STOP_LOSS_LIMIT','TAKE_PROFIT','TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT') NOT NULL,
  `timeInForce` enum('GTC','IOC','FOK') NOT NULL,
  `orderQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `orderPrice` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `stopPrice` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `icebergQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `originalClientOrderId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `currentExecutionType` enum('NEW','CANCELED','REPLACED','REJECTED','TRADE','EXPIRED') NOT NULL,
  `currentOrderStatus` enum('NEW','FILLED','CANCELED','EXPIRED','PENDING_CANCEL','PARTIALLY_FILLED') NOT NULL,
  `orderRejectReason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastExecutedQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `cumulativeFilledQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `lastExecutedPrice` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `commissionAmount` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `commissionAsset` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transactionTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tradeId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `isOrderOnBook` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `isTradeMakerSide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `creationTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cumulativeQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `lastQuoteAssetTransactedQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  `quoteOrderQuantity` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: **Is there a way to put those queries in some kind of queue?**, what you need is a `transaction`. i hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285300) can guide you to the right steps. you might want to ensure the `FILLED` order can made if and only if the `NEW` order exists.

Comment: But I thought that a transaction couldn't work, because I just start 2 transactions, because the same function gets called twice right? And a single transaction can have multiple queries, but I only know one response per function call. Could you please write me a simple example in my case how I should use the transaction? And what if a NEW order doesn't exist? How do I wait for the NEW order and then execute the other query again?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Are both queries the same IODKU?  (I think I know the answer, but I need to see these to be sure.)

Comment: I have added the result of that query to the bottom of my question :)

Comment: Just to make sure... Both queries are the same, because the same method is called twice!

Comment: Have you tried using a promise?

Comment: It's about the callback in the websocket. The websocket calls the same function twice, so when the order occurs, the 2 functions don't know each other, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not a binance bug, it is pretty sure that the websocket callback events come in the right order as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804721/can-websocket-messages-arrive-out-of-order). As a first step you should double-check this with `console.log()` in the beginning of the callback function. Further I assume that the `Order.executionReportToOrder` is simple synchronous glue code.

If all this is true the overtaking must appear later in the following asychronous processing. Then you can try to use a mutex-lib like [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex) to preserve the order of the callback execution like this:

```
exports.subscribeAccount = async (agentId) => {
    binance.websockets.userData((response) => {
        console.log("Add some meaningful debug information here!")
        mutex.runExclusive(() => {
            console.log("Add some meaningful debug information here!")
            if (eventType === "outboundAccountPosition") {
                console.log("outboundAccountPosition")
            }
            else if (eventType === "executionReport") {
              const order = Order.executionReportToOrder(response, agentId);
              order.save();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: The order of the response is correct, so the overtaking indeed takes place in the callback handling

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "... takes place in the callback handling"? So you have checked the order in the websocket network communication and there it is correct? And you have checked the order with `console.log` in the beginning of the callback-handler? Is it still correct there? Or sometimes already wrong? Please be very precise!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have checked the order of the incoming responses from Binance, which turned out to be the correct order. Than I printed the same response right before I execute the query. At that point the order is still correct. But when they both call Order.save() the second callback gets executed faster (sometimes). Then it leaves an order in the database with status=NEW instead of status=FILLED

Comment: Then I hope the mutex-solution above works for you. If not, there are still other possiblities to solve such synchroniszation issues by using DB-features e.g. `insert into ... select ... where not exists (...)` [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert#913929). If you need help on this, please tell!